# Extrating Json response PYTHON

Tags: python

I need help my friends, it's my first project with Api, and I'm not able to pull the data from the Api, it returns the following error.

Script:

```
response = data.json()

for number in response['mobile_phones']:
    dd = resposta['ddd']
    num = resposta['number']
    whatsapp = resposta['whatsapp_datetime']
    print(dd+num+whatsapp)
```

Erro:

```
Erro: KeyError: 'mobile_phones'
```

Response Api

```
{
    "cpf": 52289257591,
    "mobile_phones": [
      {
        "ddd": 27,
        "number": "999111151",
        "priority": 1,
        "cdr_datetime": null,
        "hot_datetime": null,
        "whatsapp_datetime": "2022-03-05 00:00:00",
        "cpc_datetime": null
      },
      {
        "ddd": 27,
        "number": "998608229",
        "priority": 2,
        "cdr_datetime": null,
        "hot_datetime": null,
        "whatsapp_datetime": "2022-03-07 00:00:00",
        "cpc_datetime": null
      },
      {
        "ddd": 27,
        "number": "992250660",
        "priority": 3,
        "cdr_datetime": null,
        "hot_datetime": null,
        "whatsapp_datetime": "2022-03-12 00:00:00",
        "cpc_datetime": null
      }
    ],
    "ip": "135.199.5.98",
    "plan": "Consulta simples"
  }
]
```

Comment: If that's the JSON that the API is returning, it should work. But maybe the `mobile_phones` key is optional, so you should test whether it exists first.

Comment: `if 'mobile_phones' in response:`

Comment: Is your posted response JSON missing a starting bracket(`[`)? There's one at the bottom but not at the top - which I think is also related to the issue you're having if the response is an array of objects which have a "mobile_phones" key on them then that's why it doesn't work because it should be something more like response.json()[0]["mobile_phones"]

Comment: Maybe is because your Python version you must have to exchange ' for ". Sometimes json not accept '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
for number in response[0]['mobile_phones']:
    dd = number['ddd']
    num = number['number']
    whatsapp = number['whatsapp_datetime']
    print(dd, num, whatsapp)
```

`response` is a list, which has dictionary of values.

The list you are looking its need to access like this, `response[0]['mobile_phones']`

Output:

```
27 999111151 2022-03-05 00:00:00
27 998608229 2022-03-07 00:00:00
27 992250660 2022-03-12 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the API actually returning an array of these objects? If so,

```py
response = data.json()

for thing in response:
    for number in thing['mobile_phones']:
        dd = number['ddd']
        num = number['number']
        whatsapp = number['whatsapp_datetime']
        print(dd+num+whatsapp)
```

though I'd generally recommend using `.get("mobile_phones")` anyways especially if this is some API you don't control so that *if* the response shape were to change ever to like "phones", your code can be more resilient to blowing up.